# Add Custom JavaScript to Admin Theme

Tags: admin, javascript

Using Magento 2.4. I want to add some custom JS in the admin area.

app\code\ClientQuote\AdminTheme\view\adminhtml\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            adminTheme: 'ClientQuote_AdminTheme/js/client-admin'
        }
    },

    paths: {
        'custom-script': 'ClientQuote_AdminTheme/js/client-admin'
    }
};
```

I can see the above in the source of /static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js

app\code\ClientQuote\AdminTheme\view\adminhtml\web\js\client-admin.js

```
define([
    'prototype'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    alert("andrew");
    console.log('andrew');

});
```

Nothing is output.

Looking at the other scripts in requirejs-config.js they all seem to added in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to Add Custom JS File in Magento 2 Admin Panel:**

1. Create `app/code/ClientQuote/AdminTheme/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js` file with the following code:

`var config = {    paths: { 'custom-script': 'ClientQuote_AdminTheme/js/custom-script' }, shim: { 'js-file-alias': { deps: ['jquery'] } } };`

1. Upload the JavaScript `custom-script.js` file at `app/code/ClientQuote/AdminTheme/view/adminhtml/web/js/`
2. Put the following code in your .phtml file to load the JavaScript file

**Note** : add `.phtml` file via `layout.xml`

`<script> requirejs(['jquery', 'custom-script'], function($){ // Your Code }); </script>`

4. Run the following commands:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: I put my JS code in custom-script.js and a .phtml file? This is the confusion I have. Some tutorials say JS file and others .phtml

Comment: You can create .phtml file according to you. It is not fixed...